# When i POST a URL with Headers with Body data it is working fine in J METER -HTTP API request i get the following Error

Tags: api, jmeter, postman, performance-testing

In POSTMAN when i POST a URL with Headers with Body data it is working fine and getting Response as 200,but when i POST the same in J meter HTTP API request i am receiving the following Error.

Headers size in bytes: 124
Body size in bytes: 54
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 404
Response message: Resource Not Found

Comment: Please share the request info

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending the same requests you should be getting the same responses. [HTTP Status Code 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) means that [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) path is not correct so you need to check the path of your URL as most probably there is a difference there. Even non-printable characters which you cannot see in JMeter GUI are encoded into their equivalents so whitespace becomes %20 so pay attention to literally everything.

---

In any case given you can successfully execute the request in Postman it means that you can record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording, the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   [image]

   once JMeter creates a Test Plan for your - expand and start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Prepare Postman for recording, [configure it to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/proxy/):

   [image]
3. Run your request in Postman
4. That's it, JMeter should capture the request and save it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) along with the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) containing corresponding request headers